# Qt 5 under Ubuntu (GTK) - no default 'Open File' Dialog

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

I've been using Qt5 installation from `apt-get` under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Now I uninstalled that, and installed from the Qt website. The problem is that now the 'Open File' dialog is not the GTK's default anymore, but the Qt's minimalistic version (see Picture below):

[image]

How do I reactivate GTK's default 'Open File' dialog, as in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: If you downloaded Qt 5.7, they deleted the library that renders Gtk styled widgets. But all Qt apps (not only the file dialog) should look in plastique style.

Comment: @isamert isn't it possible to re-activate it somehow?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. But they added StylePlugins according here[1] which serves same purpose. I couldn't managed to get it work, it has some bugs I assume(or could be packaging problems, I dont know). I'm using Qt version 5.6 for now.

[1]: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications